# ListView Shows Recent Image taken from camera

Tags: android, listview

In my code when i take image from camera it shows correctly in imageview. But when i take second image, both listview items shows same picture..Old picture replaces with new one..when i take third picture then all of three items show same result.and so on..Please can anyone solve my problem.

```
public class CustomerRegistrationL0 extends Activity {
int take_image;
int UploadFile;
static SimpleAdapter Adapter;
static Bitmap thumbnail;
static String encodedImageString;
Bitmap image2;
 LayoutInflater  mInflater;

 Uri selectedImage ;
 static ListView listviewattachment;
  public ArrayList<ListItem> myItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
 private MyAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cr_l0);        

    //declare fields
    final EditText textcnic=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextCNIC);
    final String cnic=textcnic.getText().toString();
    final EditText textmobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMob);
    final String mobileNo=textmobile.getText().toString();
    final EditText textname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    final String name=textname.getText().toString();
    final EditText textaddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextAdd);
     final String address=textaddress.getText().toString();
    final EditText textkin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextKin);
    final String nextkin=textkin.getText().toString();  


       listviewattachment=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //make listview scrollable manuallly(shit)
       listviewattachment.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int action = arg1.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Handle ListView touch events.
                    v.onTouchEvent(arg1);
                    return true;
            }
        });

     //////////////// // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Button buttonCamera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera);
    Button buttonFromGallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAttach);
    Button formSubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit); 

    buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            startActivityForResult(i, take_image);

        }   
});


    buttonFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                intent.setType("*/*"); 
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                            UploadFile);
          }

         });        

    formSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           


     public void onClick(View v) {


        validate(textcnic,textmobile,textname,textaddress,textkin);

     //decoding bytes


        String attachedImage=encodedImageString;

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObj.put("CNIC Number", cnic);
            jsonObj.put("Mobile Number", mobileNo);
            jsonObj.put("Name", name);
            jsonObj.put("Address", address);
            jsonObj.put("Next Kin", nextkin);
            jsonObj.put("Image",attachedImage);
            String jsonString=jsonObj.toString();
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             try {

                File myfile = new File(sdcard,"JSONCache.json");
                myfile.createNewFile();

               Writer myOutWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myfile));
              myOutWriter.write(jsonString);
              myOutWriter.close();

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "File Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "COuld not create file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
             //end of write json object

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //write json object

}
    });


}

private void validate(EditText cnic, EditText mobile,
        EditText name, EditText address, EditText kin) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(name.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        name.setError("Please Enter Name");

    }
}


 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK )
        { 
            if (requestCode==UploadFile){

                // Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                // if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedImage.getScheme())) {
              //  String[] filePathColumn = { "_data" };

                //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                 //       filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                //cursor.moveToFirst();

                //int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_data");}
              //  String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
              //  cursor.close();
                // }
                // else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedImage.getScheme())) {
   // String path= selectedImage.getPath();}


            /*  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { "data"};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();*/
      }


        if (requestCode == take_image) {


           //get image
              thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  



              BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

              factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;




              int imageWidth = factoryOptions.inDensity=50;
              int imageHeight = factoryOptions.inDensity=50;

             image2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, imageWidth , imageHeight, true);

                //////listview work


            listviewattachment.setItemsCanFocus(true);
              myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
              ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
               myItems.add(listItem);

              listviewattachment.setAdapter(myAdapter);
              myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ////////////////////end of listview work

             ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


             thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
             //encode image
             byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
              encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        }

        }
}

  public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return myItems.size();
        }

        public ListItem getItem(int position) {
            return myItems.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview2, null);


                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                holder.Delete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }


            holder.image.setImageBitmap(image2);

            holder.image.setTag(position);
            holder.Delete.setTag(position);

            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    final Dialog imgDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

                  imgDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                  imgDialog.setCancelable(false);
                  //   layout imageview2 is used because when i use simple imageview layout dialogue with imageview and closebutton,  
                  //   every taken image at instancewill not be shown in dialogue.
                  imgDialog.setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
                  Button btnClose = (Button)imgDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);
                  ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)imgDialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);


                  BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();


                 int imageWidth = factoryOptions.inDensity=400;
                  int imageHeight = factoryOptions.inDensity=500;
                  //thumbnail is selected coz if we select bm to enlarge it will give poor quality(bm is small sized image)
           Bitmap Scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(CustomerRegistrationL0.thumbnail, imageWidth, imageHeight, true);

                  ivPreview.setImageBitmap(Scaled);

                  btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View arg0) {

                          imgDialog.dismiss();
                      }
                  });
                  imgDialog.show();
                       // ListItem listItem = new ListItem();

                        //myItems.add(listItem);

                       myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //listviewattachment.setSelection(myAdapter.getCount()+1 );

                }
            });


            holder.Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    if (tag != (myItems.size() )) {
                        myItems.remove(tag);
                        Log.d("GCM", "Item removed from " + tag);
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    class ViewHolder {

ImageView image;
        Button Delete;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your `getView()` you do not consider the position. You always set the bitmap to `image2` which is the most recent bitmap: `holder.image.setImageBitmap(image2);`

I think you misunderstood how get view works. The `getView()` method is called for each item in the list when you `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The solution is to keep reference to the different bitmaps in a list (or elsewhere.. i am just giving a possible solution),

```
List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you get the image from the result, add it to the `images` list.

```
image2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, imageWidth , imageHeight, true);
images.add(image2)
```

Finally, `setImageBitmap` based on the position of the item during `getView()`

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
```

Comment: thanks Amulya Khare..you are great..thanks for helping me in these small issues....:)....